# Can I copy text from current webpage and pass it to chrome extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension

`Can i copy content from webpage and fetch it in chrome extension.  I am using-` chrome.tabs.executeScript( { `code: "window.getSelection().toString();" })`

I declared scripting in manifest.json but it giving me error Uncaught TypeError: chrome.tabs.executeScript is not a function

Is there other way to do this OR how i can do this using window.getSelection().toString();

`chrome.tabs.executeScript( {`
`code: "window.getSelection().toString();"`
`})`

I declared scripting in manifest.json but it giving me error Uncaught TypeError: chrome.tabs.executeScript is not a function`

Comment: There's no such function in ManifestV3. It's now in chrome.scripting and its syntax is different.